# How to get a beacon to count individual devices nearby for visitor monitoring on daily basis?

Tags: google-beacon-platform

I'm trying to figure out how difficult would it be to get a beacon (let's say iBKS Plus) to count individual connections nearby for visitor monitoring in outdoor recreation areas (non-profit). It should separate the user-ids and count the same user only once a day (if the same device is detected multiple times during the same day). Final results would need to show only the amounts of individual visits per day with a time stamp (dd-mm-yyyy). And all this should be done with pretty much zero coding experience :) Thanks in advance if there's someone willing to help.

Comment: What programming language are you using and what's the context? Showing your code will also help us answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is possible, but it requires a custom app to be installed on all visitor cell phones (both Android and if desired iOS) to detect the beacon, and report the detection to a server to increment counts.  This is no project for a beginner programmer as it requires:

1. Learning the fundamentals of building an Android (and iOS) app
2. Learning the fundamentals of detecting bluetooth beacons using Android (and iOS) SDKs.
3. Learning to build server-based web services to report the detections.

For an experienced programming to build a working prototype with minimal user interface on one mobile platform (Android or iOS) would take perhaps 20 hours.   For a beginner with zero programming experience, even if there is plenty of aptitude, this could take many months of learning to accomplish the same.